# Undefined method when logging out of an account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am working on a login/logout system, however I am having difficulty actually logging out and destroying sessions. I am getting "NoMethodError in SessionsController#destroy", an undefined method for my "forget" method.

Here are my methods in my sessions helper.

```
def forget(user)
    User.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def log_out
    current_user && forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
```

And my sessions controller:

```
  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to_root_url
  end
```

Here's my logout link in cass I made some mistake here:

```
<%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, method: :delete, class: "dropdown-item" %>
```

I tried passing current_user to the forget method but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `def forget(user)` method, you are calling `User.forget` and not `user.forget`.  It looks like `forget` is intended to be an instance method and not a class method, which is how you’re calling it.